# Building Android Project (Zxing) with ANT

Tags: java, android, ant, build, zxing

I am new to Android and the Ant based build process. I want to build the project barcode scanner [zxing](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) hosted in the google code. I downloader the source and followed the build procedure in the [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GettingStarted).  The project builds at the root level  but I  get an error when I perform ant operation inside the android folder.  The commands I used are as in wiki:

```
cd ../android 
ant debug 
ant install
```

The error is :

BUILD FAILED
/Users/StackUnderflow/Projects/zxing-read-only/android/build.xml:98: Cannot find /path/to/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml imported from /Users/StackUnderflow/Projects/zxing-read-only/android/build.xml

How and where do I set the path to the android-sdk the ant build is looking for? The build process produces an ZXing-2.2.zip but how do I build an apk file to load in the device?

Comment: Ditch ANT, switch to Maven. Then find xzing core here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.zxing%7Ccore%7C2.1%7Cjar

Comment: @ChristopherPerry Maven doesn't contain the Android app because it's not a library. The poster is trying to build the .apk

Answer (score 2):

The error says it right there. You didn't follow this step, or rather, you didn't change the path!

```
echo "sdk.dir=/path/to/android-sdk" > local.properties
```

Comment: I added the path of the sdk to local.properties . I now get the following error :      [aapt] invalid resource directory name: /Users/StackUnderflow/Projects/zxing-read-only/android/res/drawable-xxhdpi

BUILD FAILED
/Applications/eclipse/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:598: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/eclipse/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:627: null returned: 1

Comment: Sounds like your Android SDK is pretty out of date